# Cannot get HTML tags from dhtmlx with C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, dhtmlx

I am trying to scrape data from [this webpage](http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=11403770140000603).

Can some one help me solve this and get the HTML tags or get the XML or JSON? I think it's encoded with something other than gzip.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15");
            using (Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does your code fail to do what you want? Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Answer (score 0):

Usually site like the one you linked, after loading the raw html ( that is what you obtain with the call you shown in your code ) launch many other Ajax call to fill various information on the page. You  need to study these call in order to understand how to fetch the data. For example you can monitor the network traffic with `F12` on `Chrome` and look at the `Network` tab.